# Sufficient Oil Distribution after Cranking for a Long Time?

Tags: oil, cold-start, wear

It's getting about time to de-winterize the ski boat this year, and I got to thinking about what happened last year.

It has a carbureted Chevy 350, and the winterizing process involves spraying a can of preservation goop into the intake until it dies.  So it takes a bit of cranking to clear enough goop out that it can catch again.

Meanwhile, I'm cranking and cranking and cranking and occasionally pumping the throttle until it starts, and it's easy to have it catch mid-pump and rev up quickly.

**When it catches mid-pump and revs up, I'm concerned about excessive wear because it doesn't have oil yet, from having sat all winter...or does it?

Is the extra-long cranking before the first start of the season, enough to distribute the oil so that it's no different from a normal startup?**
Or perhaps even better than a normal start, since a normal start seems to catch almost immediately, with almost no time to distribute the oil first?

Comment: While [this does not answer your question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/17932/4152), it should give you a visual about how the oil system works in the SBC.

Answer (score 5):

The ideal method requires a moderate level of mechanical skills. There is a tool available (small block Chevy oil pump primer) that turns the oil pump with out cranking the motor over. The distributor is removed, the tool is essentially a distributor shaft with most of the parts missing. The end of the tool turns the oil pump which circulates the oil through the motor. Reinstalling the the distributor is somewhat complicated but possible with a good YouTube video.

Comment: Fitted cams and distributors and never needed a youtube vid to do it...

Comment: I did that when I rebuilt my '97 Jeep engine.  That's an I6, but the same idea - leave the distributor off, put a big flat screwdriver bit with a socket extension on a drill, and run the pump until you get oil up top.  Then put the distributor on, wonder why it doesn't run very well, fuss around a bit, figure out that the distributor is one tooth off from the camshaft, take it back off again and reinstall...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a 4-stroke engine then it will have an oil pump.

This starts to turn and deliver oil as the engine starts to turn - it may require a fews turns to pick up oil from the sump. The more turning you do to get it started, the more oil is pumped around the oilways.

When I start a re-built engine for the first time I remove the plugs and spin the engine until the oil gets to the valve gear and/or the oil gauge shows pressure.

I have also re-purposed a fuel pump to pump fresh oil into one of the oil galleries, which then goes through all the galleries. Often there are removable plugs at the ends of some of the galleries which you can use for access, make sure you are connecting after the pump and not before otherwise you just pump oil into the sump - depending where, and if, a non return valve is fitted.

Some engine test beds have priming pumps for fuel and oil and some of our lab engines at university had oil priming pumps fitted for the same reason...

Comment: The oil pump in a SBC sits at the bottom of the oil pan submerged in oil, so it does not have to "pick up oil" as you say, it is always primed and ready to go..

Comment: @Moab I worded my answer to be applicable to more than one engine in the hope of more people being able to find it useful.

Comment: I get that but the question involves a specific engine, you could add it to your answer citing it is engine specific.

Comment: The fools at Buick did not put the oil pump in the pan on the 350 ( engine  X in 1980 era). It had to suck the oil up about 6 in..

Comment: So a problem for Buicks when sludge plugged the oil inlet screen.

Comment: So it sounds like I *do* have oil where it needs to be, by the time it catches for the first time of the season.  The only difference between your first method and what I've been doing is that I leave the plugs in.  Just crank until it goes.

Comment: @AaronD and dry contact with no oil under compression causes damage...

Comment: @SolarMike How does that compare to a normal start?  Like if I ran it last weekend and I'm taking it out this weekend, and it did nothing in between?  That usually catches in about a second.  Not much cranking at all then.  Has enough oil drained out from weekend to weekend to make it worse than the first start of the season, where it cranks for a couple of minutes before it accelerates to idle?  
I'm not going to pull the plugs every weekend, so the question is really about the comparison between the two situations.

Comment: @AaronD your question was about the several months of non-use over winter. Weekend to weekend the oil will still leave a residue, even after months there will still be a layer of oul but do what you want - I explained how I start engines left for a ling period of time as that was what your original question was about. If you don’t want to remove the plugs then din’t - there is no law about this.

Comment: @SolarMike Why the defensiveness?  I'm just probing for detailed understanding that covers all the points in the original question.  The bold part is my initial concern, which you and mikes have both answered.  The last sentence of the original question is the comparison.